# Invalid cookie header: Negative max-age attribute

Tags: scala, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm to get content from HTTP server using apache HttpClient. My HttpClient object use `BrowserCompatSpec` class for processing cookies.

Some time server to return HTTP response header like this:

```
"Set-Cookie: foo=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=-1404230328; path=/; domain=.domain.com"
```

During processing response in HttpClient I get warning:

```
Jul 01, 2014 8:15:12 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: foo=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=-1404230328; path=/; domain=.domain.com". 
Negative max-age attribute: -1404230328
```

As a result `foo` cookie not removed and had old value.

Max-Age attribute description from RFC2109:

```
Max-Age=delta-seconds
      Optional.  The Max-Age attribute defines the lifetime of the
      cookie, in seconds.  The delta-seconds value is a decimal non-
      negative integer.  After delta-seconds seconds elapse, the client
      should discard the cookie.  A value of zero means the cookie
      should be discarded immediately.
```

I think what - `BrowserCompatSpec` working correctly and this issue is a server's defect. But I can't to influence of server behavior.

How ignore this warning and set `foo` cookies as expired without intervention into HttpClient lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in [documentation (3.4. Custom cookie policy)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html). Using this manual I write `mySpecProvider` that create new cookie specification with overridden max-age attribute handler.

```
val mySpecProvider = new CookieSpecProvider {
    override def create(context: HttpContext): CookieSpec = {
        val spec = new BrowserCompatSpec()
            spec.registerAttribHandler(ClientCookie.MAX_AGE_ATTR, new MyCookieMaxAgeHandler())
            spec
          }
        }
```

Then I create new register:

```
    val cookiesRegistry = RegistryBuilder.create[CookieSpecProvider]()
      .register("myspec", mySpecProvider)
      .build()
```

And added register in client builder

```
val clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
  .setDefaultCookieSpecRegistry(cookiesRegistry)
```

Config for using new cookie specification

```
val reqConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
  .setCookieSpec("myspec")
```

`MyCookieMaxAgeHandler` look like:

```
class MyCookieMaxAgeHandler extends BasicMaxAgeHandler {

  override def parse(cookie: SetCookie, value: String) {
    try {
      if (value.toInt >= 0)
        super.parse(cookie, value)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        throw new MalformedCookieException("Invalid max-age attribute: " + value)
    }
  }

}
```

After all this manipulations negative max-age attribute ignored.